# Why my question is migrated to stack-overflow ?

Tags: discussion, support

Hello I want know the reason for which [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240659/text-compression-in-c-or-c) is migrated to stack-overflow? If this is not considered as a code-golf I will like to cite few example where compression in without standard library is the only way to solve the problem,for example [MONS](https://www.spoj.pl/problems/MONS/) and [MAGIC2](https://www.spoj.pl/problems/MAGIC2/)

Every year one question also features in TLE (a shortening/optimizing contest where only C and C++ is allowed)

I have seen these type of question common in few others contest too,so I was inquisitive to compare various compression techniques and there utilization in code-golfing in order of get an idea about the most shortest and efficient compression technique feasible for implemenatation,however I am interested to know why this question is not suitable for codegolf.stackexchange, since as i am looking for shortest possible compression technique my question is not suitable for stack-overflow itself.

Comment: I felt that the question was phrased in a way that you were asking for advice or help with code samples. Additionally, the question was quite vague and it wasn't clear to me whether you were asking for the code size to be minimized, or the smallest compressed result. I felt that the question was neither a code-golf or programming puzzle, so SO seems a more appropriate place for your question. This site is not SPOJ or TLE, so not every problem from those competitions will necessarily translate into a suitable CGSE question.

Comment: I believe that Text compression can be proper code-golf :-) Now,no I was only asking for some advice about compression techniques that can be implemented int those languages and some pointers in the right direction,I agree that this site is not SPOJ or TLE,but do you really think stack overflow is the right place for that question? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

*Although I'm a mod, I write this answer as a user of this site. My opinion should not be construed as some sort of "official" opinion.*

Code challenges on Code Golf SE are supposed to appeal to a wide range of coders. Most of the coding challenges here allow solutions in any number of languages, to encourage creativity.

Making a challenge specific to C and C++ is not a good way to appeal to a wide audience. One comment I heard was that your question sounded more like you wanted someone to write a program for you, rather than being a genuine code challenge.

There is *no good reason* for a text compression challenge to be restricted to specific programming languages. **If your question needs language restrictions in order to be interesting, then it isn't very interesting to begin with, and is a poor fit for this site.**

Again, in this instance I speak as a user of the site, not as a site moderator. I just happen to feel strongly about question quality, as you can see in my recent meta posts.